# C - Copy string into a linked list variable

Tags: c, string, linked-list

```
#define STRLEN 65

/*Create linked list */
struct node {
   char str[STRLEN];
   struct node *next;
};

newInput = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
strcpy(newStr, newInput->str);
```

I left the other parts of the code, but it doesnt seem to be copying the string into newInput->str.

The string accepted is only 64 bytes.

It's just blank when I print it out after the copy. Any clue why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have the arguments to `strcpy` reversed, the first argument is the destination, the second argument is the source.  Try:

```
strcpy(newInput->str, newStr);
```

Comment: Or even better, `strncpy(newInput->str, newStr, STRLEN);`

Comment: `strncpy` is the **wrong** function to use here. It zero-fills the remainder of the size, which is a waste of time, and if `newStr` were longer than the destination size, it would not get null-terminated. **Never** use `strncpy` unless you really know what it was designed for.

Answer (score 0):

You have the arguments to [strcpy](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) reversed.

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of [`strcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcpy/) is the destination and the 2nd param is the source.

So

```
strcpy(newStr, newInput->str);
```

should be

```
strcpy(newInput->str,newStr);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your destination and source are backwards:

```
strcpy(newStr, newInput->str);
```

should be

```
strcpy(newInput->str, newStr);
```